# get html node inner text segmented?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, html-parsing

I am trying to parse html page and I am facing a problem which is that I want to get the inner text of a node segmented i.e iterate on html node children assuming each text segment as a in child:

```
<node1>
This text I WANT on iterate#1
<innernode>This text I WANT on iterate#2</innernode>
This text I WANT on iterate#3
<innernode>This text I WANT on iterate#4</innernode>
This text I WANT on iterate#5
</node1>
```

I am using [htmlagilitypack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) as a parser but I think that I will face this problem with any other html parser

Comment: why not use standard .net xml classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your .NET  version, you could use an extension method that works on the node you want.
I havent used the html agility pack, so this is a mix of C# and psuedo-code.

eg

```
public static List<string> GetTextSegments(this HtmlNode node)
{
    string nodesText = ... // get the nodes text
    yield nodesText;

    List<HtmlNode> innerNodes = ... // get the list of inner nodes with a 
    // query like node.SelectNodes("//innerNodes")
    foreach(HtmlNode iNode in innerNodes)
    {
        string iNodeText = ... // get iNodes text
        yield iNodeText;
    }
}
```

You could then call this like so:

```
HtmlNode nodeOfTypeNode1 = ... // 
foreach(string text : nodeOfTypeNode1.getTextSegments())
{
    Console.WriteLine(text);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get your goal, use SelectNodes with XPath.

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(content);//content is the variable containing your html.
var items = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/node1//text()");
foreach (var item in items)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.OuterHtml.Replace("\r\n",""));
}
```

Comment: but when I use this way I can't handle html nodes I mean I cant get the name of the node or its attributes or its children

Comment: What you want to do is to get all of texts regardless of inner text and node as your case. If so, how about `DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//text()")`?